# Getting binding to work with Popupcoloredit

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, devexpress

I am trying to get colorpicker working for my program and I'm having trouble with it keeping the value on reinitialization. I was wondering if I'm missing something or if popupcoloredit initialization is overwriting the value. On viewmodel initialization it keeps the strings and bools I have but the Colors are reset without the setter being called so I think it's being destroyed.

My XAML is as follows:

```
<TextBlock Text="{x:Static meta:MetaCommon.Text}" Style="{StaticResource ContentHeader}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
<dxe:PopupColorEdit Name="TextColour" Text="{Binding TextColour}" MinWidth="130" Margin="0,0,0,10" />
```

I then use it in the textbox

```
<TextBox Text="Sample text..." Margin="0,0,0,10" Name="TextBox1"
     Foreground="{Binding Path=Color, ElementName=TextColour, Converter={StaticResource ColorToBrushConverter}}"
     Background="{Binding Path=Color, ElementName=BackgroundColour, Converter={StaticResource ColorToBrushConverter}}" />
```

C# is simply a get set

```
public static Color TextColour { get; set; }
```

Comment: What Color class are you using? `System.Windows.Media.Color`, or `System.Drawing.Color`?

Comment: @EdPlunkett tried it with both. Neither works.

Comment: See update. Got it working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't bind to `PopupColorEdit.Text`. [Bind to `PopupColorEdit.Color`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/DevExpressXpfEditorsPopupColorEdit_Colortopic). And because it's DevExpress, always be on the lookout for their habit of neglecting to set `BindsTwoWaysByDefault = true` on dependency properties where they should. This is one such property. By default, the `Color` property of `PopupColorEdit` never updates the property you bind to it. This is correct approximately never, but it's the default they shipped it with.

```
<dxe:PopupColorEdit 
    Name="TextColour" 
    Color="{Binding TextColour, Mode=TwoWay}" 
    MinWidth="130" 
    Margin="0,0,0,10" 
    />
```

Your viewmodel property must be `System.Windows.Media.Color`, not `System.Drawing.Color`:

```
public static System.Windows.Media.Color TextColour { get; set; }
```

And lastly, you must implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` properly in your viewmodel and raise `PropertyChanged` when the value of `TextColour` changes or else those other bindings, on the `TextBox`, will have no way of knowing that anything changed.

Comment: Worked perfectly, Thank you very much!

Comment: The multiple Color types got me, thanks for the assist.